# No database provider has been configured for this DbContext in debug

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to debug and this error occurs from nowhere

I have searched but nothing works anyone can help me?

My code

StartUp.cs

```
 public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddScoped<IDAL, DAL>();
    }
```

DAL & IDAL.cs (It's in this file the error shows up!

```
namespace CalendarioTrabalho.Data
{
    public interface IDAL
    {
        public List<Evento> GetEventos();
        public List<Evento> GetMeusEventos(string userid);
        public Evento GetEvento( int id);
    }

    

    public class DAL : IDAL
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        public List<Evento> GetEventos()
        {
            return db.Eventos.ToList();
        }
        public List<Evento> GetMeusEventos(string userid)
        {
            return db.Eventos.Where(x => x.User.Id == userid).ToList(); 
        }
        public Evento GetEvento(int id)
        {
            return db.Eventos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring an instance of ApplicationDbnContext in a field, instead of getting it from Dependency Injection (via constructor injection)?

Comment: @mason My controller

public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly IDAL _idal;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IDAL idal)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _idal = idal;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Eventos"] = JSONListHelper.GetEventoListJsonString(_idal.GetEventos());
            return View();
        }
    }

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is in telling me that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>` will register the `ApplicationDbContext` in the DI container, `private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();` just initializes new instance of context with no relation to the DI (and setup happening there). If you want to leverage the DI, modify `DAL` to accept the context as ctor parameter and initialize the field with it:

```cs
public class DAL : IDAL
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;

    public DAL(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Read more:

- [.NET dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection) or [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
- [DbContext Lifetime, Configuration, and Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();`
Instead add a **constructor** to your DAL class with ApplicationDbContext as a parameter.
It will automatically resolve the ApplicationDbContext from the **Dependency Injection container** as it is already configured in startup.cs in Configuration class with the connection string.

[Read more about Dependency injection and Entity framework core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

```
public class DAL : IDAL
{
    //private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;

    public DAL(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    public List<Evento> GetEventos()
    {
        return db.Eventos.ToList();
    }
    public List<Evento> GetMeusEventos(string userid)
    {
        return db.Eventos.Where(x => x.User.Id == userid).ToList(); 
    }
    public Evento GetEvento(int id)
    {
        return db.Eventos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

You have already used DI in your controller correctly to inject IDAL as a dependency to controller below.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger; 
    private readonly IDAL _idal; 
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IDAL idal) { 
        _logger = logger; 
        _idal = idal; 
    }

    public IActionResult Index() { 
        ViewData["Eventos"] = JSONListHelper.GetEventoListJsonString(_idal.GetEventos()); 
        return View(); 
    }
}
```